# Customizing UIBarButtonItem "Done" style and "Plain" style separately using UIAppearance

Tags: iphone, ios, customization, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I know how to customize `UIBarButtonItem` using `-setBackgroundImage: forState: barMetrics:`, but I would like to use different images for `UIBarButtonItemStyleDone` and `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain`.

Is there a way to accomplish this using the `UIAppearance` protocol?  Or do I have to set the image each time I want a "Done" style button?

(I tried messing around with code like the following:

`[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];`

But that just sets every bar button with the "Done" image.)

Thanks!

Comment: Do u want to change the back image on  button click?

Comment: I've customized the back button already.  I'm looking to have different "normal" bar buttons (like how iOS uses a blue button for "Done" and "Save" but gray for things like "Cancel").

Comment: @James, One option is to use a custom subclass for Done button as `CustomDoneBarButtonItem` from `UIBarButtonItem` and use it as `[[CustomDoneBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone]`. Whenever you are adding a done button, create an object of this custom class and add it.

Comment: This does not work, because when you call `appearance` on the subclass, it calls `appearance` on the superclass, and all your UIBarButtonItem's get this style. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022468/how-to-use-uiappearance-to-style-a-subclass-but-not-the-superclass

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In **iOS 6** you can use the new method of UIBarButtonItem class:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage
                  forState:(UIControlState)state
                     style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style
                barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

It sets the background image for the specified state, style, and metrics.
More details are available [in the Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/setBackgroundImage:forState:style:barMetrics:)

So to change the appearance of all UIBarButtonItems you can use something like:

```
UIImage *doneBackgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_done.png"]
   resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 4, 0, 4)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:doneBackgroundImage
                                            forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: it is official API, available in iOS 6 only (which I stated explicitly). It solves exactly the problem described: "way to accomplish this [different images for UIBarButtonItemStyleDone and UIBarButtonItemStylePlain] using the UIAppearance protocol".

Comment: yes sorry the downvote doesnt make sense did read it wrong - totally my bad! correct. thanks for that :) i need ios5 though... else it would be easy

Comment: No problem, I'm also looking for the good solution for iOS 5 ;-)

Comment: I was looking for a solution for iOS 5 as well when I asked the question, but since it's not specifically stated, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Any ideas how to customize the text title attributes for UIarButtonItemStyleDone? setTitleTextAttributes:forState: is missing the style parameter;(

Answer (score 10):

**for IOS5***

The only way I found is using a UIBarButtonItem category:

UIBarButtonItem+Appearance.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIBarButtonItem (Appearance)

+ (void) setupAppearance;

@end
```

UIBarButtonItem+Appearance.m

```
#import "UIBarButtonItem+Appearance.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIBarButtonItem (Appearance)

+ (void) setupAppearance {
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance]  setBackgroundImage: [[UIImage imageNamed:@"customButton"]
                                                                  resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8)]
                                                       forState: UIControlStateNormal
                                                     barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance]  setBackgroundImage: [[UIImage imageNamed:@"customButtonHiglhighted"]
                                                                  resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8)]
                                                       forState: UIControlStateHighlighted
                                                     barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];



    Class klass = objc_getClass("UIBarButtonItem");
    Method targetMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(klass, @selector(setStyle:));
    Method newMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(klass, @selector(__setStyle:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(targetMethod, newMethod);
}

- (void) __setStyle:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style {
    [self __setStyle:style];

    if(style == UIBarButtonItemStyleDone) {
        [self setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"customDoneButton"] resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8)]
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"customDoneButtonClicked"]
                        forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    } else {
        [self setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"customButton"] resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8)]
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"customButtonHighlighted"]
                        forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
}

@end
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.
Credit for this solution goes to https://gist.github.com/2633081

Comment: Is this [MethodSwizzling](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MethodSwizzling)? If yes there is always risk of appstore rejection.

Comment: @acb yes it is, but I know many apps that do it and while this does in no way legalize this, I _feel_ its ok **in this case**

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work with some system controllers, e.g. on MFMailComposeViewController.