# Button image for UIControlStateSelected not working after customizing UIBarButtonItem through UIAppearance

Tags: iphone, ios, customization, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I've customized `UIBarButtonItem` in my AppDelegate.m using `UIAppearance` and all the bar buttons are showing the correct images in normal and selected states.

I want "Done" and "Save" buttons to use a different image (so they appear to be blue instead of gray), so I use `-setBackgroundImage: forState: barMetrics` to set two different images for `UIControlStateNormal` and `UIControlStateSelected` in `-viewDidLoad`.

The image for `UIControlStateNormal` is working fine, but the `UIControlStateSelected` one isn't showing, instead it shows the original image I used for selected states in AppDelegate.m.  If I comment out the original image the new (blue) one is shown properly.

What's the proper way to set different background images for specific buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `UIControlStateHighlighted` is what you are looking for.

A `UIBarButtonItem` goes into the highlighted state whenever it receives the user touch. `UIControlStateSelected` is typically for UI elements which toggle between two states.

Comment: Thank you! I tried `UIControlStateSelected` and it worked for the plain style bar buttons that I customized in AppDelegate.m so I thought it was the right one. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: Btw, do you know if there's a way to set all `UIBarButtonItemStyleDone`with a custom image? I tried asking in this question but got no response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583574/customizing-uibarbuttonitem-done-style-and-plain-style-separately-using-uiap